# readlink not working when called remotely over ssh

Tags: centos, ssh, ansible

I am testing some ansible roles using molecule and testinfra. After running the tests in debug mode I can see it attempting to call `readlink -f '/sbin/init'` to check if systemd is symlinked. Here is the remote command below:

```bsh
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o User=myuser -o Port=22 -i /Users/myuser/.cache/molecule/jenkins-config/default/ssh_key -o ConnectTimeout=10 99.999.9.999 \'sudo /bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'readlink -f /sbin/init\'"\'"\'\''
```

Running this command from the ansible host with high verbosity shows why this current test is failing.

`bash: sudo /bin/sh -c 'readlink -f /sbin/init': No such file or directory`

However when running this command locally on the ansible target..

```bsh
$ sudo /bin/sh -c 'readlink -f /sbin/init'
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
```

Shows correct output.

I am not too sure why this is failing in a remote session and I'm out of ideas to get more information to help solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your call seems to use an overly complex amount of quotes. This line works:

```
ssh <your-options> <target-host> "sudo /bin/sh -c 'readlink -f /sbin/init'"
```

(Be careful, if a password is required, using `-S` option for sudo will make  password typing visible.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `sudo` or `bash` to run the command on the remote system.

Just

```
ssh <options> <user@hostname> readlink -f /sbin/init
```

should be enough.